# How can i setup my wamp server to access to a virtual Host from intranet?

Tags: php, apache, wamp, virtualhost, wampserver

I have some virtual-host and I can access it on the PC that has the server intalled. But I have others Pc and I want to access via the domain name.

I just can access to the server configuration page changing the statement "Require local" to "Require all granted". This only allow me to access through the ip address.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName laravel5.1.app
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp64/www/laravel5_1/public"
    <Directory  "d:/wamp64/www/laravel5_1/public/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the site using your domain names you must tell each of the other PC's where to find the domain name.

So you either need a local DNS Server or you edit the HOSTS file on each PC that you want to access the site from by adding something like this to the other PC's HOSTS

```
192.168.1.100 laravel5.1.app
```

Assuming your WAMPServer (Apache) is running on ip address 192.168.1.100

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly , as you said, I had to install a Dns Server instead of edit all Hosts file. I installed Simple DNS Plus running on windows 10. Do you have other option without cost than that?